# Method must be overridden in [proguard.classfile.editor.AttributeAdder] if ever called

Tags: android, admob, proguard, android-proguard

I'm updating `com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads` from 15.0.1 to 17.1.1 and I'm getting the following error when attempting to run the app:

> Method must be overridden in [proguard.classfile.editor.AttributeAdder] if ever called

When I go back to 15.0.1 everything works fine. When I disable Proguard everything works fine.

I have no idea what this error is about and it's sporadically mentioned in some ancient questions that don't seem to apply any more.

Edit: I've found a workaround - to add `-optimizations !class/merging/*` to my proguard but I'd still like it to work the way it's supposed to.

Answer (score 5):

Add this to your proguard-rules file

```
-optimizations !class/merging/*
```

Fixed my problem.

Seems to be a ProGuard issue, based on this thread [HERE](https://sourceforge.net/p/proguard/bugs/688/)

Comment: Using a more recent version of the Android Gradle plugin should solve this issue (e.g. v3.2.1 should use ProGuard 6.0.3 which has this issue fixed).

Comment: @T.Neidhart maybe you can also look at that issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53607066/android-build-release-transformclasseswithdexbuilderforrelease-failed-java-lang